# Qt dialog blocks alt+tab hotkey on Gnome3

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gnome

I have a Qt5 application with custom dialog inside. When the dialog is opened, system Alt+Tab hotkey (which allows to switch between application) does not work. Shell is Gnome 3, and OS is Debian.

The code which creates a dialog is very simple:

```
MyDialog* dialog=new MyDialog();
dialog->show();
```

And the dialog class has only constructor looking like this:

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget* parent)
:QDialog(parent)
{
    setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());
    setWindowTitle("Test");
    layout()->addWidget(new MyWidget());
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Is the dialog modal?

Comment: @KubaOber it is WindowModal

Comment: Looks like a window manager bug, perhaps.